# Не могу найти ошибку в коде . Python

Tags: python

`Задание 5 тема 5 Яндекс практикум основы Phyton , где ошибка?

Мой код :

```
DATABASE = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}
def process_friend(name, query):
    # Проверяем, есть ли имя name среди ключей словаря
    if name in DATABASE:
        city = DATABASE[name]
        print (f'{name} в городе {city}')
    else:
        print (f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}')# Если имя есть в словаре - проверяем, что передано в query
        if query == 'ты где?':
            # Если в переменной query передан вопрос "ты где?" -
            # получаем из словаря значение (название города) по ключу name
            city = DATABASE[name]            
            return (f'{name} в городе {city}')# тут строка "имя_друга в городе название_города"
        else:
            return '<неизвестный запрос>'


def format_friends_count(friends_count):
    if friends_count == 1:
        return '1 друг'
    elif 2 <= friends_count <= 4:
        return f'{friends_count} друга'
    else:
        return f'{friends_count} друзей'

def process_query(query):
    elements = query.split(', ')
    if elements[0] == 'Анфиса':
        return process_anfisa(elements[1])
    else:
        return process_friend(elements[0],query)
        
def process_anfisa(query):
    if query == 'сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(DATABASE)
        # Вызовите функцию format_friends_count() и передайте в неё count.
        # Отредактируйте строку ниже: в ней должно использоваться выражение, 
        # которое вернёт функция format_friends_count()
        return f'У тебя {format_friends_count(count)}.'
    elif query == 'кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ', '.join(DATABASE)
        return f'Твои друзья: {friends_string}'
    
    elif query == 'где все мои друзья?':
        unique_cities = set(DATABASE.values())
        cities_string = ', '.join(unique_cities)
        return f'Твои друзья в городах: {cities_string}'
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'


print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
print(process_query('Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, где все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто виноват?'))
print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
print(process_query('Коля, что делать?'))
print(process_query('Антон, ты где?'))
```

Не принимает
Мой результат :

```
Привет, я Анфиса!
У тебя 7 друзей.
Твои друзья: Серёга, Соня, Миша, Дима, Алина, Егор, Коля
Твои друзья в городах: Красноярск, Челябинск, Москва, Пермь, Омск
<неизвестный запрос>
Соня в городе Москва
None
Коля в городе Красноярск
None
У тебя нет друга по имени Антон
<неизвестный запрос>
```

А должно быть :

```
Привет, я Анфиса!
У тебя 7 друзей.
Твои друзья: Серёга, Соня, Миша, Дима, Алина, Егор, Коля
Твои друзья в городах: Красноярск, Челябинск, Москва, Пермь, Омск
<неизвестный запрос>
Соня в городе Москва
<неизвестный запрос>
У тебя нет друга по имени Антон
```

?что исправить?

Comment: Начни тут: [ask]

Comment:  что дальше ?

Comment: @Артём дальше сюда: [edit]

Comment: @Артём нет, вы не правильно исправили вопрос, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с данным ответом: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120)

Comment: Учту про изображение, невнимательно читал , исправил

Comment: А как вы **искали** ошибку в коде?

Comment: Уже нашел, искал ошибку в том что сам добавлял в код , а она оказалась в изначальном шаблоне кода к этому заданию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика: Проверяете текст на содержание в нем вопроса "ты где?", если нет этого вопроса, возвращаем `'<неизвестный запрос>'`, если есть, проверяем далее по условию.

```
def process_friend(name, query):
    # Проверяем, есть ли имя name среди ключей словаря
    if 'ты где?' in query:
            # Если в переменной query передан вопрос "ты где?" -
            # получаем из словаря значение (название города) по ключу name
        if name in DATABASE:
            city = DATABASE[name]
            return f'{name} в городе {city}'
        else:
            return f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'# Если имя есть в словаре - проверяем, что передано в query          
    else: 
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'
```

Функцию замените и получите нужный результат

Comment: В практикуме часто путают . Давая изначально неверный шаблон, с которого надо начать код , в итоге  я принимаю как истинный , проверяю всё что добавил сам , а ошибка крылась в шаблоне по умолчанию и нигде не сказано что его можно менять.

Comment: В общем курс бесплатный , почему бы мне не пройти его , сталкиваясь с трудностями я тут жду помощи , вы отвечая на вопрос получаете рейтинг , за помощь вам спасибо

Comment: Просто получая готовые ответы на такие простые задачи, большого понимания не появляется. В вашем случае нужно научиться правильно выстраивать логику, просто в голове для начала проговорите "если то то, то ..., иначе то ...", таким образом вы бы и сами пришли к этому решению. Попробуйте, не тратить время на решение сложных для вас задач, а поиграться с интерпретатором. Продумайте какую нибудь простую логику, а затем попробуйте записать её. Так гораздо больше понимания получите. А научившись правильно выстраивать логику, вы уже сможете двигаться дальше.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за советы 